# communication with sd card arduino

Tags: optimization, arduino, spi

I have a problem with communication with the sd card on Arduino.I do this configuration.I have an Arduino Mega so the code is:

```
pinMode(53,OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(53,HIGH);
if(SD.begin(4)){
    Serial.println(F("All ready for SD"));
}else{
    Serial.println(F("SD Failed"));
}
```

I have the SD on an Ethernet shield.So i noticed that sometimes i get error on SD and sometimes i get all ready. Some errors come when i have the Ethernet cable plugged but it is not only this reason i get error also when i don't have the cable plugged.

Comment: it appears you have properly negated the W5100's chip select as not to interfere. The default speed of the SD library is Half, should be slow enough. Does the W5100 work, alone? To completely rule out the W5100. I would hold pin 2 of IC1 to GND and see how the SdCard works (alone). This will put the W5100 into reset. Though, I would not do it too long as it may damage the CAT811 in IC1. If possible lift pin 2 and then jump trace to GND. You may also want to try a different SdCard. I have seen differences that make start up problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Since it i worked at mega and SD card is on Ethernet shield the solution is to set high the digital pin 10 to stop the SPI connection with ethernet shield in order to speak to the card.